# Dimension-Wise Distances in a n-dimensional structure

Tags: combinatorics

Apologies for not knowing the actual name of the structures that I'm looking into. They are of the form `a^b`, which might be a regular cube `(2^3)`, or something else entirely.

I'm searching the amount of steps (in each dimension) to 'reach' every vertex, starting from a corner.

[image]

For the 2x2x2 case (see picture), it's pretty much Pascal's Triangle:

- 1 Vertex (the origin) can be reached by going (0, 0, 0).
- 3 Vertices can be reached by going (1, 0, 0), which is, just linear direction.
- 3 Vertices can be reached by going (0, 1, 0), which is 2D-diagonal
- 1 Vertex can be reached by going (0, 0, 1), which is 3D-diagonal

For the 3x3x3 case, I found the following (manually):

- (0, 0, 0) = 1
- (1, 0, 0) = 3
- (0, 1, 0) = 3
- (0, 0, 1) = 1
- (2, 0, 0) = 3
- (0, 2, 0) = 3
- (0, 0, 2) = 1
- (1, 1, 0) = 6
- (1, 0, 1) = 3
- (0, 1, 1) = 3

Which adds up to 27, great.

I'm looking for a solution that gives me these values for any `a^b` (both the steps and the number of occurences). I've used 3D in my examples, because that's the easiest to show, but I might have a 2x2x2x2x2x2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there $d$ dimensions, and the side length of the cube is $s$. In your first example, $d=3$ and $s=1$. This is `(s+1)^d` in your notation.

Every one of your "direction sequences" is a tuple, $(a_1,\dots,a_d)$. These tuples all satisfy
$$
a_1+\dots+a_d\le s,\\
a_i\ge 0
$$
Conversely, any tuple solving the above is a valid direction sequence. Using stars and bars, you can show that the number of valid direction sequences is $\binom{d+s}d$.

The final point of each path can be described in Cartesian coordinates as $(x_1,\dots,x_d)$. One of the possible points is given by
$$
\begin{align}
x_1&=a_d\\
x_{2}&=a_{d-1}+a_d\\
x_{3}&=a_{d-2}+a_{d-1}+a_d\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
x_d&=a_1+\dots+a_d
\end{align}
$$
For example, the direction sequence $(0,1,1)$ from your second example bring you to $(1, 1+1,1+1+0)=(1,2,2)$, which means the point with $x$-coordinate $1$, $y$-coordinate $2$, and $z$-coordinate $2$. This is not the only point you can reach, since you can permute the coordinates arbitrarily, to also reach $(2,2,1)$ and $(2,1,2)$.

To compute the number of points you can reach, you need to compute the number of ways to permute the coordinates $(x_1,\dots,x_d)$. This is given by a certain multinomial coefficient. For each $i\in \{0,\dots,s\}$, let $n_i$ be the number of copies of $i$ occurring in $(x_1,\dots,x_d)$. Then
$$
\text{number of points reachable using $(a_1,\dots,a_d)$}=\frac{d!}{n_0!\cdot n_1!\cdots n_{s}!}
$$
Therefore, you just need to generate all tuples of nonnegative integers with length $d$ and sum at most $s$, then use the above formula to compute their multiplicity. Remember, for each $(a_1,\dots,a_d)$, you compute $(x_1,\dots,x_d)$, then use that to compute $(n_0,n_1,\dots,n_s)$, then use that for the above formula.

Comment: Okay I've read this 4 times now. I think I get it. Kind of.
Thank you so much for the reply, I'll chew on this after some sleep.

Comment: Looks good, thanks!